# Can people from Neverland time travel?

Tags: pan-2015

I just watched *Pan*, and in it, Blackbeard has a line:

> Here you join orphans alike, from every corner of the globe. Every
>   race, creed, and color. Every age and era.

My interpretation of this line is that he's traveled through time to find orphans at various points (which could explain his love of Nirvana (if you haven't seen the movie, I recommend it at least once for this alone)).

Aside from this, is there a history of anyone leaving Neverland and traveling to varying times?

Comment: I haven't seen this film, but in other versions of the story, time in Neverland simply doesn't exist in the same way as in our world. There is no such thing as "the 21st century" in Neverland. That is all. Everything else is overthinking, which you shouldn't do too much about fantasy stories.

Comment: I thought it was that Neverland exists in another 'dimension' and when you are there you never age, therefore when someone from 'present time real world' would be from a different era the the ones already there and the ones who will arrive in the future. PS the use of Nirvana is shocking and an abomination!

Comment: @Seamusthedog: I agree about PS sentiment. However, I think the film lends to the interpretation that he's gone to the 20th century (where he heard Nirvana), and back to the 19th when he kidnapped Peter. What you're suggesting, I believe, is still a linear progression of time outside of Neverland, am I correct?

Comment: That was ment to be comment not answer

Comment: @PiousVenom e 'linear progression' yes, always been my interpretation. I don't know of any Peter Pan stories that discuss what time he is from either. I have only seen this film once and the Nirvana bit made my skin crawl (Dave Grohl on Ryan's Mystery Play date comes a close second.  PS whoever downvoted my 'answer' needs to take a breath, didn't wait 1 minute till I had deleted it!